# Why the forward function of Llama2 gets such confusing loss?

Tags: nlp

I am trying to test Llama2's performance on a specific dataset by using the forward fuction.Here I have a vesy simple compound "every dirty hat." And I tried to input the compound into the forward fuction of llama2 in order to get its loss.
But I get a confusing high result. Did I make mistakes in my code or I just use the wrong method?

Here is the code:

```
comb = "every dirty hat."
model_name = "/home/llama/llama-convert-7b/"
from transformers import LlamaForCausalLM, LlamaTokenizer,T5ForConditionalGeneration, T5Tokenizer
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained(model_name).cuda()
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name,use_fast=False)
encode = tokenizer(str(comb) + tokenizer.eos_token, return_tensors='pt')
input_id = encode.input_ids.cuda()
attn_mask =encode.attention_mask.cuda()
loss = model(input_ids=input_id, labels=input_id,attention_mask = attn_mask).loss
import torch
print(torch.exp(loss))
print(loss)
```

The Loss is :tensor(8.2856, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)
The ppl is :tensor(3966.3806, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=)

Comment: I have already tried the comb without the period and using tokenizer without eos_tokens, It gets an even higher loss. Is there anything wrong with the tokenizer?